# PHP Laravel ключ - значение

Tags: php, laravel

Сделал запрос к БД:

```
$val = DB::table('users')->select('downloads')->where('id', 1)->get();
```

И получил:

```
[{"downloads":3}]
```

Как получить `3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по выводу, так: `$val[0]->downloads`

Comment: ErrorException: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @MikeWaters, ах, каюсь, исправил ответ. моя ошибка.